# Change values in a row if the primary key is not present in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
UPDATE Customers,OrderLine
Set customerID = "---"
Where Customers.customerID != OrderLine.CustomerID;
```

I'm not too sure how to make this work 
What it is meant to do is change the values in customerID to --- but only if that value is not present in the CustomerID column in the OrderLine table

Comment: Why would use you `'---'` instead of `NULL`?  How do bad customer ids get input anyway?  You should have proper foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column like `customerID` is I guess the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table `Customers`, right?
 
If this is the case then simply you can't update more than 1 row to `'---'` because this would create duplicates and this is not allowed.

If this is not the case then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE Customers 
SET customerID = "---"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM OrderLine
  WHERE Customers.customerID = OrderLine.customerID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT IN:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Customers.customerID = "---"
WHERE Customers.ID NOT IN (SELECT OrderLine.CustomerID FROM OrderLine);
```